# Using the Maven classifier as a dependence

Tags: maven, build, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a bunch of projects in a workspace where each project has its own `pom.xml` which generates its own **zip** with a classifier called **foo** using the **maven-assembly-plugin** as below:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals><goal>single</goal></goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>foo</classifier>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>foo.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have one more project where I intend to copy all of the jars generated in the above projects with the **foo** classifier using the **maven-dependency-plugin** as below:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
                                <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <classifier>foo</classifier>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <!-- similar artifactItem tags for project, 2, 3, etc -->
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <classifier>source</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But I get a error with these pom files saying: **Failure to find Project1:jar:foo:{version}-SNAPSHOT in {http://repositoryURL} was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of proxy-central has elapsed or updates are forced.**

I don't understand why maven is trying to download it from the repository when I just intend to do a copy from local builds. The other projects do have the appropriate archives generated. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you need `mvn -U ...`.

Comment: I did try with the update-snapshot flag, I still get the same error.

Comment: That is not possible. The error "was cached in the local repository" went away. Maybe it was another one but it definitely wasn't that one.

Comment: Sorry, but it is the exact same error word-to-word :).

Comment: It simply can't be. Running `mvn -U`  _explicitely_ tells Maven not to have this error. Please post your exact log in your question after running your command.

Comment: Ugh.. found the error. In the dependency when I specify `<type>zip</type>`, then I get a build success. It was trying to find the `jar` from the repository when I was generating a `zip` in other projects. I should probably delete the question.

Comment: Ah, I was not going crazy :D. You can delete if you want yes :).

Comment: :) Thanks for the help! I was going crazy too as I could not see anything wrong! I'll just let the question be and then answer it myself. Maybe it helps someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was generating archives of type **zip** in other projects, and assembly project pom was trying to find the **jar** since I had not specified the type in the **dependencies**. Once I added `<type>zip</type>` it was all good!